# RegOpenKeyEx giving error 2 or error 161, fails both ways

Tags: c++, winapi, registry, windows-server

I am trying to read a registry key from a Windows server, and I can't seem to get it to work either with or without leading slashes.  If I try:

```
lError = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "\\SOFTWARE\\Company\\Product\\ServerName", 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hDomainKey);
```

It gives me error 161, which is ERROR_BAD_PATHNAME. (The specified path is invalid.)

Okay, so trying it this way:

```
lError = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Company\\Product\\ServerName", 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hDomainKey);
```

I get error 2, ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. (The system cannot find the file specified.)

I can open `regedit` and see the value I want to retrieve, with path `My Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Company\Product`, name `ServerName`, and type `REG_SZ`.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open the key, not the value:

```
lError = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                      "SOFTWARE\\Company\\Product",
                      0,
                      KEY_QUERY_VALUE,
                      &hDomainKey);
```

and then read the value using [`RegQueryValueEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (or [`RegGetValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: +1. Note that RegGetValue works on Vista and later only. Consider `RegQueryValue` or `RegQueryValueEx` if you need to support earlier than that -- but watch out for null termination problems.

Comment: Zoinks!  I have `RegQueryValueEx` following the code I posted, but I misunderstood the relationship between the two calls.  Thanks.  I'll accept this in a few minutes when the time limit elapses.