# RegOpenKeyExW with HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE returns 2 on Windows Embedded 7 64 bit

Tags: c++, registry, windows-7-x64, windows-7-embedded

I need to read key values in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE from my application. I use the following snippet to do that but it always returns 2.

```
std::wstring strTmp;
strTmp = L"SOFTWARE\\TEMP";
RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strTmp.c_str(), 0, KEY_READ, &hKey))
```

But when I use `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` then I'm able to read information successfully from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE`. I understand that my application is unable to read from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` due to access privileges. I did run my application with administrator privileges (using Run As) but that did not help me out.

Can someone shed some light on how can I access the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` using `RegOpenKeyExW`.

I did go through the links [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809003/regopenkeyex-giving-error-2-or-error-161-fails-both-ways), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252297/why-is-regopenkeyex-returning-error-code-2-on-vista-64bit?rq=1) but that did not help me out,

Comment: Windows error code 2 is ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. Are you sure that your registry key exists?

Comment: Your code also looks to be missing an open flag. Use KEY_WOW64_64KEY to access the 64 bit view or KEY_WOW64_32KEY to access the 32 bit view (i.e keys under Wow6432Node).

Comment: @ Mohamad Elghawi Yes the Registry key exists. But still it returns 2. Also I monitored the registry path using Procmon, and it displays the right path when this call is made but windows says file not found. Also as you advised I had tried with flag KEY_WOW64_64KEY combined with KEY_READ but no luck.

Comment: I had downloaded the procmon from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.

Comment: What is the full path to your key. Is it HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TEMP or is it HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Temp?

Comment: When I checked the registry path with the assistance of procmon I observed it as HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TEMP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My apologies for my misunderstandings. Actually I had to use `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` flag instead of `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` in `RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strTmp.c_str(), 0, KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_32KEY, &hKey))` to get my application working. Thanks to Mohamad Elghawi.